# Creating points with linear referencing

Tags: distance, arcgis-pro, linear-referencing, events, point

I have traffic data that shows tracks that have start and end times (in YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS format) and the speed (m/s) the vehicle was moving. From that I've calculated total traveled distance (m) and distance traveled in one minute (m).

Each feature represents one track (line) with specific speed. For one vehicle there are thousands of features.

Example:
    ID    V_name   st_time             
        end_time                 speed    distance    distance_1min
1      Vehicle1   20181115-140505    20181115-140610   10             650           600
2      Vehicle1   20181115-140632    20181115-141018   8.5        1921          510
3      Vehicle1   20181115-141018    20181115-141249   6            906           360
    etc.

I need to create points along the line that are one minute apart from each other. So along some features there will be only one point (ID 1 in the example table) and along other ones there will be several (IDs 2 and 3 in the example table). I've used [Linear Referencing](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/an-overview-of-the-linear-referencing-toolbox.htm) -toolbox to Create Routes and used Make Route Event Layer -tool to create points as events, using the distance_1min as the Measure Field. The problem is that the tool only creates a point once within the determined distance along the tracks, when I would need it to create several when fit. Would anyone have an idea how to fix this?

This would only be the first step. The second one would be to find out a way to create "continuous" point features throughout the data, meaning not beginning from the start point of each track (like in the first step), but taking under account the "residue" (m) left from the previous feature. This way the points would be one minute part in the whole data, not only by each track.

Example:
    ID    V_name   st_time             
        end_time                 speed    distance    distance_1min   residue 
1      Vehicle1   20181115-140505    20181115-140610   10             650           600                    50
2      Vehicle1   20181115-140632    20181115-141018   8.5        1921          510                    441

Any ideas?